# how to Drop multiple pin's on same Location

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, annotations, mkmapview

Hi is that possible to display multiple User Pin's on `MKMapView` at same location Lat Long. see this Bellow Image:-

[image]

in This above image i can there is a Two user location pin but Because of same Lat long i can see only one pin. so my question is that is that possible to display multiple pin on same location.

if we can't drop Multiple Pin's on a Same location then it is possible to display multiple `AccessoryView` on one pin who contain same location user's info.

Please Guide me how to do this task.

Comment: if the lat and lon values are same then both the pins are dropped in same position if we zoom the mapview then we can see those two pins.

Comment: while i am tap on pin then simultaneously get second annotation info like HS to other user when i tap again then get HS AccessoryView i want to display both. as a pin or if cant drop both user's pin then while tap then show AccessoryView of both. this issue bcz of same location of both user

Comment: No i cant see i can do zooing with but its exactly same Lat long :(

Comment: @NitinGohel do u have sample for this.its shows only one annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a custom MKAnnotation class to do this.

There is no meaning in dropping multiple pins at same position. 
Instead you can show multiple AccessoryView in same one pin
For that you need to create UIView that list all your pin headers which you wish to show.

```
        [customAnnotationView.contentView addSubview:_contentView];
        customAnnotationView.contentWidth = _contentView.frame.size.width;
        customAnnotationView.contentHeight = _contentView.frame.size.height;
```

UIView is what you design so you can create that

Something like this can help you.[image]

Comment: can you please provide sample Code Demo i am still not Able to done tis issue.. :( please if you can

Comment: i dont undastend how to do ? can figure it out how to filter same lat long data mind is real meshed please gimi simple demo of it if you can Plz

Comment: i am already use placeMark custome MKannotatioView but realy not undastood how to do as you say...

Comment: its a coming From Webservice i have array of all detals with Dictionary right its ther many pins have same lat long.

Comment: hmm so you can get for all same lat long na ?

Answer (score 0):

First filter out the unique location records. Lets say you have 10 records to show on map and out of which 3 records have same locations and other 2 records have other same locations and rest 5 have different locations. So on map there should be total 1(for 3 same records)+1(for 2 same records)+5 = 7 pins on map.

Now in method

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation

check current annotation has more than 1 records same as annotation location and based on that do

if (ary.count > 1)
    {
        [annotationView setCanShowCallout:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [annotationView setCanShowCallout:YES];
    }
```

then in method

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view

check view can show callout of not. do following

```
if (![view canShowCallout])
{
  // means annotation has more than 1 records on same location 

 now get records of same location and display the way you want.
}
```